# How to make a shape spin for 5s

Tags: css

I created 2 shapes and have made them spin using CSS animations. Is there any way to specify how long each shape should spin for?

I want the first shape to spin for 5s and then stop, but I want the second shape to keep on spinning.

My code:

```css
#square1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-top: 135px;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation-name: square1;
}
 
@keyframes square1 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: transition-duration: 5s;

Comment: If you add your code, I can help you get the desired result

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I updated the code in the post, I tried transition-duration, didn't work

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely both that users will up-vote your posts and that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages, some styles are more appropriate than others). But, *pick one* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project.

Comment: While your HTML should be minimal, almost trivial, it would be helpful if you provide it. I've moved your CSS into a snippet, so you can easily add your HTML in the HTML section and have a good demo of what you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to change the iteration count on your animation.

You are setting a 360 deg in 1 second. Thats one loop of your animation. Now we add an iteration count to the second square so it repeat 5 times for 5 seconds.

```css
.square {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 240px;
  margin-top: 135px;
  animation: spin 1s linear;
  animation-name: square1;
}

.square2 {
  animation-iteration-count: 5;
}

@keyframes square1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="square square1"></div>
<div class="square square2"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do what the Question asks. While the second square does repeat for 5s, the request was that the first one stop after 5s, while the second continues, not stopping. While I wouldn't be pedantic of having the order reversed, your first stops after one iteration.